# mockito exception WrongTypeOfReturnValue "Optional cannot be returned by getInfo3(), getInfo3() should return List"

Tags: java, mockito, dao

I am running into an exception in my tests where mockito thinks getInfo3() is returning an Optional, but the return type is a List<>.

**mockito test:**

```
@Test
    public void searchUser() {

        when(mockUserDao.getInfo1(anyInt())).thenReturn(Optional.of(info));
        when(mockUserDao.getInfo2(anyInt())).thenReturn(Optional.of(info1));
        when(mockUserDao.getInfo3(anyInt())).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());

        when(userAPI.getUserById(anyInt())).thenReturn(Optional.of(fullUser));

        ....
    }
```

**getInfo3()**

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM info where id = :uid")
    List<Info3> getInfo3(@Bind("uid") Integer userId);
```

**getUserById()**

```
public Optional<RootUser> getUserById(Integer userId) {

        Optional<Info1> info1 = this.userDao.getInfo1(userId);
        Optional<Info2> info2 = this.userDao.getInfo2(userId);
        List<Info3> info3 = this.userDao.getInfo3(userId);

        ...

        return Optional.of(RootUser.builder()
                .setInfo1(info1)
                .setInfo2(info2)
                .setInfo3(info3)
                .setInfo4(info4)
                .build());
    }
```

Here is the error output after running the test with the test failing in when(userAPI.getUserById(anyInt())).thenReturn(Optional.of(fullUser)):

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Optional cannot be returned by getInfo3()
getInfo3() should return List
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

This is not a multithreaded test. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The below line is an extra mock that was causing my tests to fail. After removing this the exception went away.

```
when(userAPI.getUserById(anyInt())).thenReturn(Optional.of(fullUser));
```